# Difference Between Puran vs Granth

Tags: puranas

What is the Difference Between Puran and Veda?

Vedas give importance to yagna, and mantras and their chief gods are Indra Agni and Rudra.

A granth is an old scripture. Vedas Puranas Upanishads are all granths. even kama sutra is a granth

Comment: Grantha means a book. So it can be any book. Whereas Puranas, Vedas are religious texts for the Hindus. Those are called Scriptures or Shastras.